# Why does POST work when using a curl call in terminal fail when called from I

Tags: javascript, ios, xml, curl, instruments

This call to a web service works when invoked from the terminal...

`curl -X POST -d @request.xml "http://some web site"`

In this example, request.xml is a file consisting of a well formed xml statement containing the data used by the curl call. This works just fine and the server returns the expected response to the POST.

Here is the xml statement (with a few changes to hide proprietary values)

`<account token="999999999999999999999" username="test@emailaccount.com" password="111111122222233333334444455555"><login ver="3.0.7" mdmac="02:00:00:00:00:00" os="7.0" lan="en" bndl="APPL" mod="iPhone"/></account>`

When I try to call the same web service from inside Instruments using the following java script commands, the server responds with an invalid parameter statement.

```
    var host = target.host();

    var loginXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <account token=\"999999999999999999999\" username=\"test@emailaccount.com\" password=\"111111122222233333334444455555\">
    <login ver=\"3.0.7\" mdmac=\"02:00:00:00:00:00\" os=\"7.0\" lan=\"en\" bndl=\"APPL\" mod=\"iPhone\"/>
    </account>";
    var xmlLength = loginXML.length + 1;
    var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/curl", 
                                                 ["-X POST",
                                                  "-d " + loginXML, 
                                                  // "-v", 
                                                  "http://some web site"], 
                                                 5);

    UIALogger.logDebug("exitCode: " + result.exitCode);
    UIALogger.logDebug("stdout: " + result.stdout);
    UIALogger.logDebug("stderr: " + result.stderr);
```

Comment: Perhaps something in HTTP Headers ?

Comment: I've tried it with and without these headers: -H Content-Type="text/xml" and -H Content-Length=<content length>. Neither helped, so I left them out for clarity sake.

Comment: The format would be `-H "Content-Type: text/xml"`. But this wouldn't fix your `invalid parameter` error - the error you are getting is from curl itself, not the target site.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not making myself clear here. The curl version from terminal gets the response from the server I expect. The Instruments version gets a response from the server, but it's answer is that I'm sending it invalid data.

Comment: I think the problem is in the way the data is being packaged up in the Instruments version of the call. If I enter a simple URL in Instruments to some url like www.apple.com, it works... But as soon as I add a `-d ...` as an argument, to the server I'm trying to get data from, the server sends back an invalid response result.

Comment: This is the answer to my problem: curl called from Instruments considers blank spaces after the parameter to be part of the value. For example:
        `-d <?xml....>`
considers the blank space between the "d" and the "<" to be a part of the value of the parameter. The correct way to indicate the value of the parameter is this:
`-d<?xml....>`

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your XML content in quotes; that is, replace:

```
    "-d " + loginXML,
```

with:

```
    "-d '" + loginXML + "'",
```

in the call to curl. Without this, it may be treating `<?xml` as the value for `-d`, and the rest of the XML as further (invalid) parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should have put that in my OP that I had tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you run curl manually with the full XML file (or even a cut-down version) instead of a reference to the file?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine in both instances. When I ran it with the xml embedded in the curl command, the xml had to be enclosed in the single quote marks. Like this: curl -X POST -d '< xml goes here >' "http://some web site

Comment: I just realized the xml I said was in the file is inaccurate. The xml also contained this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Sorry about that. I should have more carefully checked before posting.

Comment: @Custom_Software When you ran it from the command-line, did you put the XML on a single line?

Comment: Yes, the XML was in one line. It worked equally well when in the xml file (inline or formatted as I displayed in OP).

Comment: @Custom_Software But it's in multiple lines in the code ... try removing the linebreaks from your code sample (and, adding the quotes around it).

Comment: My bad... there are no linebreaks in the javascript/Instruments version. I'd put those in last night for presentation purposes. As displayed, it wont even run in Instruments. The only way it will run is as one line. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my problem: curl called from Instruments considers blank spaces after the parameter to be part of the value. For example:
        `-d <?xml....>`
considers the blank space between the "d" and the "<" to be a part of the value of the parameter. The correct way to indicate the value of the parameter is this:
`-d<?xml....>`